# Loading 24k entries into a select list efficiently

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a classic ASP page that when loaded does a JavaScript call to another ASP page to retrieve XML to load into my `<select>` box. It has to load roughly 24k options; needless to say, this is rather cumbersome.

They don't all need to be loaded in immediately and it doesn't matter if it actually takes a while to load as long the page doesn't hang. The page needs to work in IE6+ (bummer).

I've considered that when a user scrolls past a given section it will load in 100 more, however, can't find an appropriate property that will work in IE6 for scrollbar position. I considered using `onmouseover` of a specific option (i.e. "Hover for more results...") but the event doesn't fire.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. :>

Comment: What about auto-complete field ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To anyone absolutely stuck doing this with a dropdown box the only way I could get it to not lock up the browser was using setTimeouts. In chrome this runs perfectly fine, but the lowest timeout IE can accept is something like 13MS and really hampers load times. On top of that I (personally) think it's a pretty ugly solution... but it's better than locking up the form, I guess.

```
var i = 0;
function doStuff()
{
// code to execute, ie, add items
i++;
if (i != end of loop)
{
setTimeout(doStuff, 1);
}
setTimeout(doStuff, 1);
```

Another piece of advice I found was to avoid reflows by using a code fragment or hiding the dropdown box (simply setting style.display to "none") until all the items are added.

Comment: This is a really poor solution I think. You bloat the DOM and you are presumably going to be querying the server *lots*, you will be loaded data which is not required, and wasting bandwidth. This might be suitable for a tiny website, but it is not scalable in the slightest.

Comment: If you take a step back and look at the constraints there isn't a much better option. The majority of users are going to see < 200 and the majority of users don't use it anyway. As opposed to populating this on load this doesn't hit the initial page load time and allows users to continue to use the form and even submit the form when they choose to not use this element as their search. I appreciated your answer but a custom control isn't a viable option for everyone - especially when trying to make lightweight changes to big applications.

Comment: And just to clarify... it queries once. Not sure why you would get the impression it's querying every time this runs.

Comment: Okay, so if you are querying the server once, then that means what you have to grab 20k+ items in a single hit. If these items are loaded via a dedicated mysql for isntance, it would increase the size of the transport per request, and then it all needs to be sent to the client. As you have addressed though, for a lightweight option, this will work, but it *really* isn't practical for any site that might forsee large scale traffic.

Comment: 20k+ items only if the user can see 20k+ items. ;p Like I said the solution is far from elegant or ideal but when you're dealing with maintenance on pages from the early 2k era you're stuck with the band-aid approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a service that lazy loads your items into the Select List using something like a server side backed store.

If I were to try and tackle this problem, I would go down the JsonRestStore route and using the Dojo Toolkit, to request items as they are needed, then populate them into a ComboBox/FilteringSelect.

Here are some resources for you.

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore

And here is a demo of what [Filtering Select](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.1/dojo-release-1.7.1/dijit/tests/form/_autoComplete.html?testWidget=dijit.form.FilteringSelect) can do.

Just as a final note, I might add, that loading all of these into the DOM, will always be a bad idea. You should use a grid or something, or use a predicter as they type to narrow down.

I use a JsonRestStore which powers a grid with around 5 million items. All I do is load new items as the user scrolls down the page. As they scroll, it detects that I need to pull another 25 items from the server, this kicks off a new query, and then it gets loaded into the grid.

Answer (score 0):

By "select list" I presume you mean the HTML element

```
<select>
  <option>option 1</option>
  ...
  <option>option 24000</option>
</select>
```

In short, more than 10-15 options in a select list is REALLY BAD USABILITY. So if this is your case you may want to rethink the interaction, since even rocket scientists will have a hard time finding and selecting just the right option out of 24000 options.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a fresh project and I'm stuck with what was handed to me. :/